# Is Observational Guidance in Research a Must? (Requires Research Advice)

Tags: clinical-psychology

I have a problem with a research. The variable I study is coping and the approach I take is qualitative. Usually, in qualitative research, the use of interview and observation guides is a must in my college.

However, in my opinion, observations cannot be made with coping variables in the context of research on social media users. This is then supported by Lazarus' statement that considers coping as a response to situational stressors. So, the form of coping strategies that a person does may always change. The use of coping strategies on social media may not be the same as coping strategies on family settings, for example.

Then, I tried to remove the observation guide from my research, but my supervisor said that the observation guide was a must. Are there any experts or people involved in research in this forum? Is observational guidance in research a must?